# Equivalence of two constructions of subgroup generated by subset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Given any group $G$ and a subset $U$, let $\hat{U}$ be the samllest subgroup of $G$ which contains $U$. Prove there is such a subgroup $\hat{U}$ in $G$.

**Proof:**

(a) Consider the following family of subgroups of $G$, namely $\mathcal{A}=\{H \text{ subgroup of}\  G: U\subset H\}$. It is obvious that this family is not empty since $G\in \mathcal{A}$. Let's consider the following intersection and denote it by $\hat{U}$, namely $\hat{U}:= \cap _{H\in \mathcal{A}}H$. The set $\hat{U}$ is a subgroup since the intersection of subgroups is subgroup and it is easy to check that it is the smallest subgroup containing given subset $U$. Thus we have proven the existence of such subgroup.

(b) Consider the following set consisting of finite products of elements of the set $U$ and their inverses, namely $$P=\{u_1^{\varepsilon_1}u_2^{\varepsilon_2}\dots u_m^{\varepsilon_m}: m\geq 0, \varepsilon_i\in \{-1,+1\}, u_i\in U\}.$$
Let's prove that $\hat{U}=P$.

Let's $p\in P$ then $p=u_1^{\varepsilon_1}u_2^{\varepsilon_2}\dots u_m^{\varepsilon_m}$. Thus, for any $H\leq G$ s.t. $U\subset H$ we have $p\in H$ since $u_i^{\varepsilon_i}\in H$ $\Rightarrow$ $p\in \cap_{H\in \mathcal{A}}H=\hat{U}$. Thus, $P\subset \hat{U}$.

We need to prove the inverse inclusion, i.e. $\hat{U}\subset P$. If we'll show that $P\leq G$ s.t. $U\subset P$ then $P\in \mathcal{A}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\hat{U}\subset P$.

1. Let's show that $P$ is a subgroup of $G$. If $x,y\in P$ then $x=u_1^{\varepsilon_1}u_2^{\varepsilon_2}\dots u_m^{\varepsilon_m}$ and $y=r_1^{\eta_1}r_2^{\eta_2}\dots r_n^{\eta_n}$ so $xy=u_1^{\varepsilon_1}u_2^{\varepsilon_2}\dots u_m^{\varepsilon_m}r_1^{\eta_1}r_2^{\eta_2}\dots r_n^{\eta_n}$ is also a finite product of elements of $U$ and their inverses, so $xy\in P$. Moreover, $x^{-1}=u_m^{-\varepsilon_m}\dots u_2^{-\varepsilon_2}u_1^{-\varepsilon_1}\in P$. Thus, $P$ is a subgroup of $G$.
2. If $u\in U$ then $u\in P$ $\Rightarrow$ $U\subset P$

We have shown that $\hat{U}\subset P$ and $P\subset\hat{U}$ so $P=\hat{U}$.

Is this proof correct? Especially, I am interested in the part when I am proving that $P$ is subgroup.

I am sorry if this prood is a duplicate because in those posts I saw that proofs were not detailed.

Comment: Yes, it's just fine.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, Thanks a lot, dear Jose! Am I right that the second construction is much simpler in working than the first one (intersection of subgroups)?

Comment: I don't agree. For me, the natural approach is throgh intersection of subgroups. But that's a matter of taste.